# SSIS - Process batches using top

Tags: loops, ssis

I am doing a Fuzzy mapping job on millions of rows of data (From Table A). I take top 10000 a time , process them and store the mapped rows in a different table. (Table B)

Then when I choose the next batch, I make sure that the Ids from table A, which are now in Table B are not picked for processing.

This is working fine.

How do I now get the process to loop through without me having to stop start after every iteration?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Create these variables (SourceMaxID and DestMaxID) as shown below:

[Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEvR6.png)

2. In your Control flow;
   Add an Execute SQL Task: in the SQL Statement, use the script below to get the max ID 
   from your Table A and assign the value to variable SourceMaxID.

   SELECT ISNULL(MAX(IDColumn), 0) FROM [Table A]

   Configure the result set to single row and add the variable.
3. Add a For Loop Container to your control flow.

   Drag the Data flow Task(s) you created for the fuzzy mapping into the For Loop 
   Container as shown below.
4. Add an Execute SQL TASK to the For Loop Container as shown below.

   Similar to process 1, get the MaxID from Table B and assign to variable DestMaxID

   SELECT ISNULL(MAX(IDColumn), 0) FROM [Table B]

[Control flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty1wS.png)

5. Configure the For Loop Container as shown below:

[For loop container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nW0hs.png)

Comment: Thanks Isaac. I will try this out. Currently I have it running on a manually configured For Loop

Comment: @Senevic How did you get on?